# How to use Passport.js Google OAuth2 strategy with Google api?

Tags: node.js, express, google-api, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I have added passport google oauth 2.0 to my website , it works fine.

This is the initial auth call to google :

```
router.get("/google", 
            passport.authenticate('google',  
                                  { scope:  ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", 
                                   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]
          }));
```

But when I access the Drive API , I get an error.

For example , when I use:

```
  const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth});
  drive.files.create(
    {
      .......
}
```

I get an error :

```
code: 401, errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'required', message: 'Login Required', locationType: 'header', location: 'Authorization' } ]
```

Is there a way to use tokens during login and coordinate the passport login and api access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what ist `auth` in your example?

Have you tried:

```
       const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2()
        oauth2Client.setCredentials({
            'access_token': req.user.accessToken
        });

        const drive = google.drive({
            version: 'v3',
            auth: oauth2Client
        });
```

Comment: auth in my example is ;                                                                                                              
`auth = new google.auth.OAuth2(ClientId, ClientSecret, RedirectionUrl );`                                          I tried this , but I got this error:                                                                                        `Error: No access, refresh token or API key is set.`

Comment: @Aditya have you tried to set the access_token? `oauth2Client.setCredentials({'access_token': req.user.accessToken});`

Comment: This works man . `oauth2Client.setCredentials({'access_token': req.user.accessToken});` . I was accessing the access token as `req.user.access_token` .